# How to organize a class's member functions?

Tags: c++, member-functions

I put 'sets' just after the constructors because it is related to the object setup. I split gets (put gets in inquires) and sets but not sure if this is good or not. What is best practice for organizing member functions?

**How about that?**

```
class Foo
{
// Friends go here if it has
friend ...;
friend ...;

// First public, then protected and private
public:
    // enums
    enum {...}

    // type defines.
    typedef ...;
    ...

    // Destructor and constructors
    ~Foo();
    Foo(...);
    Foo(...);
    ...

    // Sets.
    void setA(...);
    void setB(...);
    void setC(...);
    ...

    // Inquiries (including gets).
    A a() const;
    B b() const;
    ...

    // Operators.
    void operator()(...);
    ...

    // Operations.
    void doSomething();
    ...

protected:

private:
};
```

Comment: There is no true answer to this, it's all up to your own preference. If you're working on an existing project or you have guidelines to follow, you should of course follow those conventions, but otherwise it's all up to you.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to judge, it's up to your personal preference or company coding standard. By looking at your code, a few things I may not agree:

- your declarations are not ordered from `pubilc`,'protected` then private
- `friend` declaration has same effort when you declare them in private area as well. so I normally put them in private section, so it gives less noise in `public section`.

---

Below is the **declaration order** I normally use:

Use the specified order of declarations within a class: `public`: before `private`:, methods before data members (variables), etc.

class definition should start with its `public`: section, followed by its `protected`: section and then its `private`: section. If any of these sections are empty, omit them.

Within each section, the declarations generally should be in the following order:

```
Typedefs and Enums
Constants (static const data members)
Constructors
Destructor
Methods, including static methods
Data Members (except static const data members)
```

Friend declarations should always be in the private section, and the **disabled** `copy constructor` and other operators `should be at the end of the private: section. It should be the last thing in the class.

Comment: Who says enumerations are not supposed to be in the public section of a class? This is the reason I voted to close this question because it's very much opinion based.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I read a few links before regarding public enum, however, I have difficulties to find them. I will remove that part for now. :)

Comment: @billz `friend` was in `private` with OP. Also: you forgot types (other than enums, but classes, structs etc)

Comment: @Walter actually I mean he should move it down to the bottom of class. I did mention types in `Typedefs`

Comment: @billz yes, you mentioned `typedefs` but not `class`es which are entirely defined within the (outer) class defintion.